# Subquery in athena IN clause giving different results when compared to a query with list given in IN clause directly

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, in-clause

I have the following query:

```
select * 
from Table1 
where NUMid in (select NUMid 
                from Table2 
                where email = 'xyz@gmail.com')
```

My intention is to get the list of all the NUMids from table2 having an email value equal to xyz@gmail.com and use those list of NUMids to query from Table1.
When I directly put the list of NUMids (which have the email = xyz@gmail.com) within the IN clause, the data scanned is very less.
For example:

```
select * 
    from Table1 
    where NUMid in (123,456,789,345)
```

But if run the first query where the inner query also gives a list of NUMids then the data scanned is very large.

Even though logically both the queries are the same, why is there such discrepancies?
** The subquery is a small table in my case and scans only few kbs, so I am assuming it should not contribute to high data scan

Comment: The query with the IN list values specified by you is just one query. The query with the IN list values derived from a subquery is two queries, hence the term "subquery."

Comment: Can you be more specific about "data scanned is very large"? How much is scanned for the first and second queries? How big is `Table2` in total (e.g. how much does `SELECT * FROM Table2` scan)? Are any of the tables partitioned, and if so, what are the partition keys?